# sumif in ifelse condition R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a DT with multiple columns and I need to give a condition in ifelse and do the calculations accordingly. I want it to do count/sum(count) grouped by segment. Here is the DT

```
Segment  Count  Flag
A        23     Y
B        45     N
A        56     N 
B        212    Y
```

I want the fourth column as count per total count of the segment based on the flag so the out put should look something like this. For flag N it is the share of the count per segment. For flag Y, it is the revenue percentage calculation if the No(N) becomes Yes(Y) and in that case the revenue that could be earned. I am sorry as it is clumsy but kindly ask me in comments if you have any doubts.

```
Segment  Count  Flag   Rev   Value
    A        23     Y  34    ((56/23)*34)/(34+69)
    B        45     N  48    45/(45+212)
    A        56     N  23    56/(56+23)
    B        212    Y  67    ((45/212)*67)/(67+12)
    A        65     Y  69     ...
    B        10     Y  12    ...
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is this?  You have changed the expected output for the third time.  Please value others time too

Comment: I am sorry. As I advanced with the data I got to know what is that is needed. I am sorry for wasting your time but it didn't go in vain. Now I have an idea of what and how to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please refer to the guide for [asking followup questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: Thanks for your Sarcasm Arun as well as help. But it was left because it doesnt matter what values there are.

Comment: Okay, man I am lost here `B        45     N  48    45/(45+212);
    A        56     N  23    56/(56+23)`  How are these 212 and 23 different for 'N'  Or is like there is specific rules for each element.  My question is that why is `65` not included

Comment: Because that is the sum of flag Y and N. The last two rows I took so that you could get that we have to add all the Rev coresponding to Y in the denominator

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I am deleting this question because I am not able to explain clearly what I want as I can not use the original data. I will be barred for asking questions but that is better than wasting your time. Thanks a lot, again! : )

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer.  Please check if that works.

Comment: Yes, because I was wasting your time and others as well

Comment: Akrun, I want to compute that in a single line. With using ifelse condition. Is it not possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DT)`), grouped by 'Segment', create the 'Value' column by diviing the 'Count' by the `sum` of 'Count', then we update the 'Value' where the Flag' is 'N'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, Value := Count/sum(Count), Segment
              ][Flag == "N", Value := Count/sum(Count), Segment]


DT
#   Segment Count Flag      Value
#1:       A    23    Y 0.18852459
#2:       B    45    N 1.00000000
#3:       A    56    N 1.00000000
#4:       B   212    Y 0.78810409
#5:       A    43    Y 0.35245902
#6:       B    12    Y 0.04460967
```

Just checking with the OPs expected output 'Value'

```
> 23/122
#[1] 0.1885246
> 212/269
#[1] 0.7881041
> 43/122
#[1] 0.352459
> 12/269
#[1] 0.04460967
```

#### Update3

Based on the update No:3 in Op's post

```
s1 <-  setDT(DT1)[, .(rn = .I[Flag == "Y"], Value = (Rev[Flag=="Y"] *
    (Count[Flag == "N"]/Count[Flag=="Y"]))/sum(Rev[Flag == "Y"])), Segment]
s2 <-  DT1[, .(rn = .I[Flag == "N"], Value = Count[Flag == "N"]/(Count[Flag == "N"] + 
               Count[Flag=="Y"][1])), Segment]

DT1[, Value := rbind(s1, s2)[order(rn)]$Value]
DT1
#   Segment Count Flag Rev     Value
#1:       A    23    Y  34 0.8037146
#2:       B    45    N  48 0.1750973
#3:       A    56    N  23 0.7088608
#4:       B   212    Y  67 0.1800215
#5:       A    65    Y  69 0.5771471
#6:       B    10    Y  12 0.6835443


>((56/23)*34)/(34+69)
#[1] 0.8037146
> 45/(45+212)
#[1] 0.1750973
>  56/(56+23)
#[1] 0.7088608
> ((45/212)*67)/(67+12)
#[1] 0.1800215
```

#### data

```
DT <- structure(list(Segment = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), Count = c(23L, 
45L, 56L, 212L, 43L, 12L), Flag = c("Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", 
"Y")), .Names = c("Segment", "Count", "Flag"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")

DT1 <- structure(list(Segment = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"), Count = c(23L, 
45L, 56L, 212L, 65L, 10L), Flag = c("Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", 
"Y"), Rev = c(34L, 48L, 23L, 67L, 69L, 12L)), .Names = c("Segment", 
"Count", "Flag", "Rev"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hi, what is setDT

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  It is the function that convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table'

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  Okay, then no need to apply `setDT`

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion Arun but it has to do according to the flag in the second conition, for the first condition it should add up everything irrespective of flag. In that case, what to do. Editing the question.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  Yes, it is done based on the flag in the second column.  Please check the `i` condition i.e. `Flag == "Y"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143654/discussion-between-abhishek-singh-and-akrun).

Comment: Arun, the desired output is not /224 it is now /269. Please have a look at the question again

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  Updated the post.  Please check if there are any more updates in your post

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  I am not getting any error with the 'data' I posted in my post

Comment: The condition of add all is overruling the Flag Y and giving NAs against flag Y

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  I am using data.table_1.10.4 and if you use both the codes, it is updating the original column i.e. `setDT(DT)[, Value := Count/sum(Count), Segment
              ][Flag == "N", Value := Count/sum(Count), Segment]`

Comment: Arun, I realised that the example could not accomodate both the conditions here and I will have to reask the entire question

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  Whatever you have showed in the example is working fine for me.

Comment: Realized the question. Kindly have a look again if you have some time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we could have also used `dplyr` pkg for that...

Updating based on the suggestions provided by @Aramis7d - thanks!

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("Segment  Count  Flag
 A        23     Y
    B        45     N
            A        56     N
            B        212    Y
            A        43     Y
            B        12     Y")

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
      group_by(Segment) %>% 
      mutate(Value = Count/sum(Count)) %>%
      group_by(Segment, Flag) %>%
      mutate(Value = if_else( Flag == "N", Count/sum(Count), Value))
```

Comment: sure this produces the correct output as per OP's requirement?

Comment: i read the first draft and not the later edited one :-) but you did the rest part... anyways, it looks simple and meets the requirements what you just did...

Comment: it seems OP hasn't even decided yet anyway

Comment: @ManojKumar This did not work for me or maybe I did not know how to use it. You can have your laugh harder.

Comment: c'mon bro. there is no sarcasm in our comments. we all are trying to help you out.. don't take it otherwise...

Comment: @ManojKumar On the site where you are talking about how to ask questions and how to comment (which I did not know) you are making fun by using LOL of others who are trying to ask question. Still, you have answered and am not able to use it though its a great help.